# can webpack watch show more useful detail for the compilation log?

Tags: webpack

Currently it shows something like :

```
Hash: 0d2cd97fd680f5a855f8
Version: webpack 1.9.10
Time: 1926ms
        Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    vendor.js  2.11 MB       0  [emitted]  vendor
       app.js   248 kB       1  [emitted]  app
vendor.js.map  2.45 MB       0  [emitted]  vendor
   app.js.map   313 kB       1  [emitted]  app
   index.html   4.9 kB          [emitted]
    + 341 hidden modules
```

what I want is

1) the compilation timestamp ( so I know when this happened )
 2) which files are changed in this compilation
 3) in case of an compilation error, at least let me know which file cause the error ( currently it prints some info about the line number , but why not show exactly the filename ? As in case of a git pulling, I may get many files updated in one action and I can not tell which file case the problem. )

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try to just add a debug option in your **webpack.config.js** :

```
module.exports = { debug: true }
```

Or you can pass some flags to `webpack` as described here: https://webpack.github.io/docs/cli.html#display-options